# How to replace a p tag value if a radio is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want replace a p tag value if a radio is checked.

I write some JS to do this,but nothing changed.
this is my code(I use jquery)

```
<script>
$(function(){
if ($('#A:checked')) {
   $("#change_me").html('<input type="radio" value="1" name="fruit">')
 }

if ($('#B:checked')) {
   $("#change_me").html('<input type="radio" value="2" name="fruit">')
 }

}
</script>

<input type="radio" name="e" id="A" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" name="e" id="B">

<p id="change_me">
   <input type="radio" value="1" name="fruit">
</p>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the JavaScript code you have with the [following](http://jsfiddle.net/dcKRu/1/)

```
$(function(){
    $('input[name=e]').change(function(){
        if($(this).attr('id') == 'A')
        {
            $("#change_me input").val('1');
        }
        else
        {
            $("#change_me input").val('2');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `:checked` selector matches elements that are currently checked.
Writing `$('#B:checked')` returns a jQuery object containing either zero or one element.  It cannot be used directly as a condition.

Instead, you can check `if ($('#B:checked').length)` to see whether the jQuery object has anything in it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to recreate the radio button if only the value is changing.

```
$(function(){
if ($('#A:checked').size() > 0) {
   $("#change_me input[type=radio]").val('1')
 }

if ($('#B:checked').size() > 0) {
   $("#change_me input[type=radio]").val('2')
 }

}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="e" id="A" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" name="e" id="B">

<p id="change_me">
   <input type="radio" value="1" name="fruit">
</p>
```

Comment: Hi,Mark.I change what i checked but nothing happend.If I refresh the site the value will be change.I want change value with no refresh.

Comment: Thats because you are only executing the above code on page load.  You need to also bind it to an event. For instance $('input[type=radio]').change(function() { // your code goes here });